# How to know if polytope in V-representation is full dimensional?

Tags: polytopes

Let $v_i$, for $i=1,...,V$ be the vertices of a convex polytope in $R^n$. That is, each $v_i$ is a point in $n$-dimensions. How can I determine if the polytope is full dimensional?

Comment: I have no idea...I just really like your picture!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rank of $(v_2-v_1,\ v_3-v_1,\ v_4-v_1,\ \dots)$ is $n$.